# Change StatusBar color

Tags: react-native

How can I choose a color for the status bar? I found an answer here but I need it to either be globally or to set it's color in each view I have, which I couldn't figure out how to do so according to the answer I found.
I'm using React-Native and trying to change the Status bar color here:

```
<StatusBar
  barStyle="light-content"
  backgroundColor="#484A80"
/>
```

But it didn't work.
Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setBackgroundColor` method:

```
StatusBar.setBackgroundColor(this.props.color, true)
```

Comment: I tried to do so, but I got a problem of unexpected token. I also tried this:           <StatusBar
            barStyle="light-content"
            setBackgroundColor("#E6E6E6", true)>
          </StatusBar> and got the same problem.

Comment: You can't do it in JSX code. Try:

    componentDidMount () {
      StatusBar.setBackgroundColor(this.props.color, true)
    }